# I get inconsistent outcomes in Spring Data Neo4j when mapping both ends of a relationship and saving it

Tags: spring, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a `User` node with `FRIEND_REQUEST` relationships mapped to a `sentFriendRequestList` list and to a `receivedFriendRequestList` list like below:

```kotlin
@Node
data class User(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator::class)
    var userId: String?,

    @Relationship(type = "FRIEND_REQUEST", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    var sentFriendRequestList: MutableList<FriendRequest> = mutableListOf(),

    @Relationship(type = "FRIEND_REQUEST", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    var receivedFriendRequestList: MutableList<FriendRequest> = mutableListOf(),

    var email: String

)
```

The `FriendRequest` class:

```kotlin
@RelationshipProperties
data class FriendRequest(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var friendRequestId: Long?,

    /**
     * Represents the receiver in an OUTGOING relationship and the sender in an INCOMING relationship.
     */
    @TargetNode
    var friendRequestOtherNode: User

){
    constructor(friendRequestOtherNode: User) : this(null, friendRequestOtherNode)
}
```

When saving multiple friend requests, on some occasions all previously created relationships disappear from the given nodes and only the newly created relationship appears.

I save like this:

```kotlin
fun saveFriendRequest(sender: User, receiver: User) {
        val sentFriendRequest = FriendRequest(receiver)
        val receivedFriendRequest = FriendRequest(sender)
        sender.sentFriendRequestList.add(sentFriendRequest)
        receiver.receivedFriendRequestList.add(receivedFriendRequest)
        userRepository.save(sender)
        userRepository.save(receiver)
    }
```

I don't understand what the problem is, especially since sometimes it runs without failure.

I created a small test project which is available on my GitHub: [link](https://github.com/S0m30n384/neo4j-friend-graph). It contains the data structure and a test class that can be run instantly. The tests show the same problem, after multiple runs it can either fail or be successful.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit unsure about the right query, but your custom Cypher statement does not return all friends and relationships for deeper links.
Changing it to:

```
MATCH (user:User{email: \$email})
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(user)-[:FRIEND_REQUEST*]-(friend:User)
WITH user, friend, relationships(path) as friend_requests
RETURN user, collect(friend_requests), collect(distinct(friend))
```

solved this for me (or the ten test runs were just randomly green).
Another solution would be, to avoid the custom query, define `findByEmail(email: String): User` and let Spring Data Neo4j create the query.

The problem that occurs is that

```
First operation:
frodo -> sam
sam -> frodo

Second operation:
frodo -> bilbo
bilbo -> frodo
```

results for *Sam* in something like `sam-frodo-bilbo`.
When you load *Frodo* or *Bilbo* the relationships are not completely hydrated to *Sam*.
The moment you save *Bilbo* (or *Frodo*), SDN will through all relationship and eventually not find the *Sam* relation. Because it is empty, SDN will remove the relationship on save.

Another problem I have seen in your code:
You should definitely annotate the manual defined constructor with `@PersistenceConstructor` because Kotlin creates an invisible copy constructor and Spring Data in general does not know which to choose. So you might randomly run into the copy constructor.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Changing the custom query didn't have any effect and the reason why I didn't use the `findByEmail` method and let the lib generate the query is because that generated query runs into a StackOverflowException. It always gets all users, then all the users based on their request, etc., resulting in az infinite loop. Thanks for the info about the `@PersistenceConstructor`! After trying out the beforementioned modifications I upgraded to SDN 6.0.7 and tried out the my original code which now seems to be working perfectly so I'm guessing a bugfix fixed my use-case as well.